# A different way to prove homeomorphism between rectangles and discs under standard $\Bbb R^2$ topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I was reading about the classical problem to prove homeomorphism between subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ a rectangle of the kind $R=\{(x,y):|x|\le a \land |y|\le b\}$ and some disc $D=\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \le r\}$.

It is clear that we can make bijections between the two spaces but the hard part is take some bijection and prove easily that $f(U)=V$ and $f^{-1}(V)=U$ for any $U\in\tau_1$ and any $V\in\tau_2$, being $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ the induced topology for $D$ and $R$ respectively.

I search for some easy geometric bijection in the literature but I ever found the same related to metrics but I dont want to use metrics because from the book where the problem arise metrics are not defined yet.

Then I thought about parallel lines of the kind $y=cx+d$ with some fixed $c\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ to make a bijection between segments from a defined range of lines that depends of some values $d_{R1},d_{R2}$ (to define all possible cuts of lines with R, from a corner to the opposite) and other range of lines that depends of some values $d_{D1},d_{D2}$ (to define all possible cuts of lines with D, from a tangent to the exterior circle to the other tangent).

Then I express $R$ and $D$ as the uncountable union of segments

$$R=\bigcup_{d=-b}^{b}\left(\{(x,y):y=cx+d\}\cap R\right)$$ and

$$D=\bigcup_{d=-\sqrt\frac{r}{c^2+1}}^{\sqrt\frac{r}{c^2+1}}\left(\{(x,y):y=cx+d\}\cap D\right)$$

> The values $-\sqrt\frac{r}{c^2+1}$ and $\sqrt\frac{r}{c^2+1}$ correspond to the minimal and maximum height $d$ of the lines with slope $c$ that cut the disc D, similarly to the heights $-b$ and $b$ for the lines of the same slope $c$ that cut the rectangle R on the corners.

Then because the segments only differ on lenght (segments from the same subspace or between $R$ and $D$) if I prove that all segments are homeomorphic to each other I think is done.

My questions are:

1. How to write properly the proof beyond this idea, and more important, it is correct? I feel is correct but a confirmation maybe very useful.
2. How to write properly the homeomorphism related to the extreme segments i.e. where $d\in\{-b,b,-\sqrt\frac{r}{c^2+1},\sqrt\frac{r}{c^2+1}\}$ that are 4 points.
3. Any improvement, commentary or critic will be very welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't just do a homeomorphism from R to R^2, and from D to R^2, after which you're done if you combine those. I think you can do that similarly as when showing an open interval is homeomorphic to reals, with tangens.  As far as your proof goes, I'm not sure "if I prove that all segments are homeomorphic to each other I think is done." follows - I understand the idea, but I'm not sure why the "sum" of the homeomorphisms will be a homeomorphism, maybe you should explain that more. Perhaps with open segments the approach could work, showing the claim for int(D) and int(R).

Comment: Yes @Jake1234, the idea behind segments is construct the homeomorphism $f: R\to D$ and from here prove that is an homeomorphism, but your idea about homeomorphism to $\Bbb R^2$ seems easier and better.

Comment: Your approach might work, but I just don't see how putting together the homeomorphisms between the segments together would make a homeomorphism. If the segments were open sets it would work, but they're not open sets. You also have an infinite amount of segments, so you can't use the fact that the segments are closed sets either. Perhaps it's worth asking under what circumstances putting together homeomorphisms will make a homeomorphism, and whether that could somehow be achieved to solve this problem.

Comment: @Jake1234 When you have $f$ you can express areas, not just isolated segments, so you can put one-to-one areas of $R$ and $D$. Open areas map open areas for any case, included the points on the circle and the perimeter of the rectangle.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Explain rigorously why putting together the homeomorphisms would make a homeomorphism. A counterexample - consider $\mathbb{N}$ spaces with discrete and cofinite topology. Identity restricted to singletons is homeomorphism between the specific singletons - so you have homeomorphisms between all the parts of $\mathbb{N}$ - but putting them together does not make a homeomorphism as clearly identity is not homeomorphism. Therefore, putting together homeomorphisms between disjunct subsets does not necessarily make a homeomorphism.